# Why use multiple col-[lg|md|sm|xs]- in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen some projects using something like

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

Why they use multiple col-?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because we can get it right for all devices for eg  small devices , medium devices, small devices, xtra small devices
Xs - extra small device
Md - medium device
Sm- small device

Comment: Do I need to specify `  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">` to get 100% width in all devices?

Comment: no. You can use the only `col-lg-12` width will be adjusted automatically for all device widths unless you want different widths for different devices

Answer (score 2):

From [the bootstrap doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro):

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal
>   to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller
>   devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element
>   will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large
>   devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.